# I can't display epub book pages

Tags: flutter, dart, epub

How I can display pages from an epub file on flutter?

I add the book but I don't know how to display it in my app
anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

most likely you will need a package for this... try using: https://pub.dev/packages/epub

Comment: I did but how I can display pages

Comment: String fileName = "asset/27112.epub";
    ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(fileName);
    print(bytes);
    final buffer = bytes.buffer;
    List<int> listInt =
    buffer.asUint8List(bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes);
    EpubBook epubBook = await EpubReader.readBook(listInt);
    print(epubBook.Chapters);
    setState(() {
      chapterTitle = epubBook.Chapters as String;

    });

Comment: this gives Dart Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Could not find End of Central Directory Record